# Format numbers in data field of SSRS Matrix with two different number types using an expression

Tags: sql-server, matrix, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, expression

So, I have an SSRS report with a matrix. The columns, rows and data field are fed by expressions that refer to parameters. Effectively giving the report a pivot table style effect.

The data field has two values in the `@prmDataField` parameter to pick from when running the report. One is called `LengthOfStay`and in the databse is all integers. The second is called `FinalCost`and in the real world would be currency (GBP in this case) but of course in the database it's just a float.

There's a 4th parameter to apply an aggregate function to the data in the data field that's as follows;

```
=SWITCH
    ( 
        Parameters!prmFunction.Value="Avg",AVG(Fields(Parameters!prmDataField.Value).Value)
        ,Parameters!prmFunction.Value="Sum",SUM(Fields(Parameters!prmDataField.Value).Value)
        ,Parameters!prmFunction.Value="Max",MAX(Fields(Parameters!prmDataField.Value).Value)
        ,Parameters!prmFunction.Value="Min",MIN(Fields(Parameters!prmDataField.Value).Value)
    )
```

***My problem***: I'm hoping there's a way to enter an expression into the Number format property of the data field textbox of the matrix so the data on the report will format depending on which of the datafield parameter values have been selected to run the report with. So if you pick `LengthOfStay`the report will display the numbers as appropriately formatted integers. If you pick `FinalCost`the report will display the numbers as currency instead.

I attempted this;

```
=SWITCH
    (Parameters!prmDataField.Value=Fields!Length_of_Stay.Value,"G-int32"
    ,Parameters!prmDataField.Value=Fields!Spell_Final_Cost.Value,"C")
```

But it didn't work and I got the following warning back once the report had run;

```
Warning 1   [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Format expression for the textrun ‘Textbox17.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format.'
```

Is it even possible to have two different number types for formatting depending on a parameter value or any other value?